# Set Flex MX Button background color using CSS

Tags: css, flash, apache-flex, flex-mx

Using CSS, how do I set the background color of a Flex MX Button? My button is declared as:

```
<mx:Button label="My Button"/>
```

And the CSS is:

```
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

mx|Button {
    color: #66ffff;
    backgroundColor: #333333;
}
```

`backgroundColor` doesn't seem to be the correct CSS property for MX Button's background color. Looking at the [Flex API docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html), I tried `fillColors` but that didn't do anything.

Is it possible to change `mx.controls.Button`'s background color using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
Button {
   fillAlphas: 1, 1, 1, 1;
   fillColors: #66ffff, #66ffff, #66ffff, #66ffff;
}
```

Even if i'd try to use an external .css file

You can create it with [Flex Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html) and import it by the following statement:

```
<mx:Style source="yourstylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: I actually tried `fillColors` but with only 2 values. Adobe's own mx Button docs (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html) appears to be incorrect in that it shows fillColors with only 2 values. 4 works, 2 does not.